# Persisting 3 or more unique activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I've got a bunch of activities which I don't want to reload because they consume internet resources. Each activity has reference-button to all other activities. Additionally, those activities must hold state and it seems that I need to use singleInstance flag - any precautions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to, when go to another activity, stop this one and save her state, I think if I have understood your problem this may be the good way to solve.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to not attempt to force a `Activity` to remain persistent in memory. This is the Android system's job, not yours. You should not rely on any `Activity` being alive once it is a paused/stopped state, since it could be destroyed at any time by the system if the device lacks memory resources. If you want to have an internet connection persist across multiple `Activity`s, you most likely want to use a `Service` instead.

It also sounds weird that each `Activity` is connected to every other `Activity`... are you sure this is the best way to allow the user to navigate your app?